# adapter for sequence to use different bus drivers

Tags: uvm

I have generic sequence that generates sequence items in order to implement algorithm. I need way to run this sequence in different testbenches where different agents  like AXI or PCIe been used. 
Probably best implementation would be adapter that gets generic item and convert them to specific agent item and starts on the agent sequencer.
Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence layering to handle this issue.

You can generate a new sequence, which will be running on `child_sequencer`, but will take the sequence_items from `generic_sequencer` like below.

```
class child_seq extends uvm_sequence #(seq_item);
  generic_sequencer p_seqr;

  virtual task body ();
    // Get Sequence Item from Parent Sequencer
    p_seqr.get_next_item (trans);  

    // Conversion of Sequence Item from Parent to Protocol Specific
    ......

    // To Start the Sequence Item on Child Sequencer
    start_item (trans);
    ....
    finish_item (trans);

    // Item Done for Parent Sequencer
    p_seqr.item_done();
  endtask
endclass
```

Now your `generic_sequencer` can look like this, which will accommodate both `child_sequence` and `child_sequencer`.

```
class generic_sequencer extends uvm_sequencer #(seq_item);
  child_sequencer c_seqr;
  child_seq c_seq;

  virtual function void build_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    c_seqr = child_sequencer::type_id::create ("c_seqr", this);
    c_seq = child_seq::type_id::create ("c_seq", this);
  endfunction

  virtual function void connect_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    c_seq.p_seqr = this;
  endfunction

  virutal task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
    // Start Child Sequnece on Child Sequencer
    c_seq.start(c_seqr);
  endtask
endclass
```

Now you can start your `generic_sequence` on the `generic_sequencer`